# Does "Vagrant package" command work in vmware fusion?

Tags: vagrant

I have VMWARE fusion on my macbook pro. In that I have a VM ,which was generated using vagrant. This VM has some changes and I want to create a .box file of out this VM.

I did see the post for the same in this forum. But did not find correct one.
I tried vagrant package but it is not working. I got the following error

*The "package" command is not supported with VMware. We recommend
taking a look at Packer (www.packer.io) as an option for creating
VMware image*s

Can anyone throw some light on the same?

Answer (score 0):

`vagrant package` currently works only for **virtualbox** VM as said from [doc](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/cli/package.html)

> This packages a currently running VirtualBox environment into a re-usable box. This command can only be used with other providers based on the provider implementation and if the provider supports it. A future version of Vagrant will address packaging boxes for other providers. Until then, they must be made by hand.